# How to submit login details to getresponse php

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to submit my username and password via a php curl request if possible to: https://app.getresponse.com/login.html

I do not see any post urls in the html code.. anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean? You dont see querystring in url?? If you are using post method then the querystring wont be visible in the url

Comment: Please post your code, So that we can help you easily.

Comment: I am trying to create a curl request that sends my login details to that page (to login).. There is no action or onclick in the form.. I am not sure how to send a post request to the page..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this curl command:

```
curl -k -L -X POST "https://app.getresponse.com/login.html" -A "Mozilla 5.8" -d "LoginForm%5Blogin%5D=__EMAIL.EXAMPLE.COM__&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=__YOUR_PASSWORD__"
```

Change `email`, and `password` with your one from above.

Comment: @sploit_ Best of luck then. You'll not get any help from me on this issue for your short and poor response. I am not a magician!